# Programmatically get list of all open tabs across all browsers using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, firefox, browser, electron

Is there a way to obtain a list of all currently open tabs across all browsers?

For context, I'm working on an electron application and I want to know when a user has certain tabs open. For simplicity's sake let's assume I'm only going to run this on Ubuntu and the browsers are all Chrome (although ideally it should work for any combination of OS and browsers)

Comment: @MemeOverload are you comfortable to have an extension in the browsers to do that?

Comment: there is a file containing this information but on windows it blocks the file from read access `C:\Users\__YOUR_USER__\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Default\Current Session` under linux you can read `~/'.config/chromium/Default/Current Session'`

Comment: @SudhakarRS as a last case resort yes, but I'd definitely want to avoid it

Comment: @HansKoch Thanks! That should do the trick for the time being for the Ubuntu + Chrome combination :)

Comment: @meme-overlord Hi, Do you find any way? I really need it.